# Import keybindings from Visual Studio to JetBrains Rider

Tags: visual-studio, import, jetbrains-ide, jetbrains-rider

Are there any extensions or whatnot for importing Visual Studio keybindings to JetBrains IDE? I just want as many 1-1 mappings as possible (Peek definition = quick definition, etc.)

Anyone knows a way?

Comment: Hey @TheForg3n1 you ever end up finding out how to import the keybindings?

Comment: I couldn't find a way unfortunately @justkeithcarr